# How can order points data in Firebase for React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase and I use real time database

[image: a busy cat]

I want to order username by points and list top 10 high points users in react native but I tried firebase order methods and I could not.

I tried like this:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('/users'); 
ref
 .orderByChild('TotalPoint')
 .limitToFirst(10)
 .on('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); });
```

but don't work

What firebase method should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this method, change my firebase rules than;

```
 {
 "rules":{
    "users":{
        "$uid":{
                ".read":"$uid === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
                }
            },
 }
 }
```

change to this =>

```
 {
 "rules":{
   ".read":true,
    "users":{
        "$uid":{
                ".read":"$uid === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
                },
            },
 }
 }
```

and try @Frank van Puffelen is sharing method is work thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You need to order on `Point/TotalPoint`, since that is the path of the value that you want to order each user on.
2. You need to handle the order of the results, since the order of items is lost when you call `val()` (as the order of the properties in a JavaScript object is undefined).

The total snippet then becomes:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('/users'); 
ref
 .orderByChild('Point/TotalPoint')
 .limitToFirst(10)
 .on('value', function(snapshot) { 
    snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
      console.log(user.val()); 
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what happens when you run this code? What does it print?

Comment: Thanks for helping,I commented on my solution but now I don't reach username I tried user.val().username.username like this print is undefined how can I reach the username below the push id

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use these methods

`.orderByChild("TotalPoint")` so you make the query based on "points"

`.limitToFirst("10")` Sets the maximum number of items equal to 10 to return from the beginning of the ordered list of results.

Comment: I tried like that=>     let ref = firebase.database().ref('/users');
    ref
      .orderByChild('TotalPoint')
      .limitToFirst(10)
      .on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });  but don't work